# Демон, слушающий сокеты на java

Tags: java, сокет, многопоточность

У меня такая проблема. Пытаюсь написать клиент-серверное приложение, в котором клиент и сервер будут общаться посредством сообщений, посылаемых через сокет.

Архитектура примерно такая:
На сервере должен крутиться сервер, который слушает два разных порта (исполнительный и управляющий). При получении соединения слушатель создает обработчик команды, который принимает строку от клиента, парсит её в объект, исходя из содержимого объекта, выполняет какие-либо действия, собирает подобный объект, но уже с ответом и отсылает клиенту.

Проблема в том, что когда я объявляю сервер демоном, слушатели портов порты не слушают.

`Main.java:`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiSocketServer srv = new MultiSocketServer();
        srv.setDaemon((boolean) true);
        srv.start();
    }
}
```

`MultiSocketServer.java:`

```
public class MultiSocketServer extends Thread {
SocketListener monitor;
SocketListener executor;
private boolean killed = false;

    public void kill() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Commencing interrupt");
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    this.killed = true;
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
}

public boolean isKilled() {
    return killed;
}
public void run() {
    monitor = new SocketListener(true);
    executor = new SocketListener(false);
    Thread mThread = new Thread(monitor);
    Thread eThread = new Thread(executor);
    monitor.master = this;
    executor.master = this;
    eThread.start();
    mThread.start();
    //чтобы не умирал
    while (!killed) {
        try {
            sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("I'm still here!");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("i guess ill die now");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

`SocketListener.class:`

```
class SocketListener implements Runnable {
public MultiSocketServer master;
public int type;
public SocketListener(boolean isMonitor) {
    this.type = (isMonitor ? 1 : 0);
}
@Override
public void run() {
    int port = (type == 1 ? 19998 : 19999);
    ServerSocket socket1;
    System.out.println("Running socket listener on port "+port);
    int count = 0;
    try{
        socket1 = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println(socket1.toString());
        System.out.println("MultipleSocketServer Initialized");
        while (!master.isKilled() && master.isAlive()) {
            Socket connection = socket1.accept();
            if (master.isKilled() || !master.isAlive()) return;
            System.out.println("Connection accepted");
            Runnable runnable;
            if (type == 0)
                runnable = new Listener(connection, ++count);
            else
                runnable = new SocketServerMonitor(connection, master);
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Проверяю всё на локальной машине через telnet. Пробовал залить на vps под управлением centOS, приконнектиться не смог. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Та же проблема у меня, на локальном все работает, на VPS не могу установить соединение, хотя статистика командой "netstat -a" отображает порт как слушающий. Может, c VPS проблема?

Comment: @hopebetrayer, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

У вас приложение завершается, не успев запуститься. Демон - это поток, который умирает при завершении приложения. Т.е. ваша программа запустилась, запустила поток и завершилась, завершив поток сервера.